Telling lie about ayat ul kursi
Assalamu alaikum brother. Suppose a man recited ayat ul kursi.but whem his mother asked to him he replied he didn't recite ayat ul kursi. Is it considered as shirk?

Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem
As Salaamu 3laykum,
I hope you and your family are doing well. It is not considered shirk. Shirk Asghar (major shirk) is when a person joined partners with ALLAAH (Glory Be To HIM). And Shirk Sagheer (minor shirk) is when a person does any form of ibadah and mixes with it being showing it off to others.
In this case a lie was told which is a sin. However, not shirk.

Have a Nice Day!

Note #1: If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.
Note #2: This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched and/or know.
